# What are if these below codes useful for?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, meta-tags

```
<!--[if IEMobile 7 ]> 
<html lang="en-US"class="no-js iem7"> 
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> 
<html lang="en-US" class="no-js ie6 oldie"> 
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 7 ]>    
<html lang="en-US" class="no-js ie7 oldie"> 
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 8 ]>    
<html lang="en-US" class="no-js ie8 oldie"> 
<![endif]-->

<!--[if (gte IE 9)|(gt IEMobile 7)|!(IEMobile)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html lang="en-US" class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

What are these useful for? What is the best and the most suitable codes as above should be in a web page?

Comment: They are used to clutter the code and make it less readable in order to support a browser that should be banned :P

Comment: Ohh so not that useful in a site isn't it?

Comment: `</sarcasm>` don't take my comment seriously.  IE is just a PITA to support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

The `<!--[if IE..` comments are generally used for including some custom code in the HTML file **only if the browser is some version of IE.**

Specifically the code you posted detects multiple versions of IE [including a Windows Phone 7 browser](http://css-tricks.com/iemobile-conditional-comment/) and defines CSS classes on the html root element accordingly.

This allows you to write CSS targetd specifically for that browser like this:

```
.iem7 .my .selector {
    /* this rule will apply only if the browser is ie on windows phone 7 */
}
```